# Angular | How to get more than two return value from .subscribe

Tags: angular, angular5, return-value, subscribe

The subscribe error is this part.

```
this.commentService
        .uploadCommentImage(formData)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
               console.log(data);
            }, (err) => {
               console.error(err); // Error occurred!
            }
        );
```

commentService.uploadCommentImage --> postImage

```
uploadCommentImage(image: any) {
    return this.apiService.postImage('/api/comment/image', image);
  }
```

The final call part is this part.

```
postImage(path: string, image: Object = {}): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient
      .post(`${environment.api_url}${path}`, image)
      .pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
}
```

The return values(.subscribe(data)) from the server are:

```
{"imageLink":"assets/comment/image/a@a.aa_a48bd8e9.png"}{"imageLink":"assets/comment/image/a@a.aa_6cb66de4.png"}
```

In this case, an error occurs on the Angular.

> ***TypeError: this._subscribe is not a function*** at ErrorObservable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe
>   (Observable.js:42)
>       at ErrorObservable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe
>   (Observable.js:28)
>       at subscribeTo.js:21
>       at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:11)
>       at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error
>   (catchError.js:43)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error
>   (Subscriber.js:83)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error
>   (Subscriber.js:61)
>       at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error
>   (Subscriber.js:83)
>       at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error
>   (Subscriber.js:61)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/OuterSubscriber.js.OuterSubscriber.notifyError
>   (OuterSubscriber.js:13)

What is the best way to avoid errors?

I only need two imageLinks.

Comment: Can you please add the relevant code you're using so we can see what's causing the error?

Comment: Can you share more of your code. Like where and how you make the call to the server?

Comment: Can you add the commentService aswell

Comment: @mika Added. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user184994 Added. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What import are you using for http

Comment: @mika constructor (private http: HttpClient)  // I use HttpClient

Comment: So is it going is the subscribe after `uploadCommentImage(formData)` being executed? If so, is it the `console.log(data)` or the `console.error`?

Comment: @user184994 yes. run subscribe after uploadCommentImage(formData). result is console.error

Comment: What happens if you remove the `.pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));` line?

Comment: @user184994 I tried it. Error occurred. // HttpErrorResponse {...error:
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 84 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:28768:51)

Comment: This is not a valid response. Ask API team to return as array of object.

Comment: Perfect. Two things: 1) Your JSON is invalid, it should be an array. 2) Your `this.formatErrors` function seems to be causing errors as well, you may need to fix that

Comment: @user184994 OK. I try It. Thank you!!!

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya OK. I try It. Thank you!!!

Comment: If you store the url of image in the database after upload the image ,Your parameter should be string otherwise I mean if you stored the image in the byte form in database then first convert to byte format and send